# React TypeScript: Stop state from making multiple api calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

As soon as the page loads I need to get the value from the URL and send it to the API, but because the state in parent objects is changing the api call is made 3 times. I want it to just call the API once.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import Context from '../components/context';
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router-dom';

interface MyProps {
  confirmationCode: string,
}

const Confirm: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<MyProps>> = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('FIRE Just Once!!!')
  });

  const { global } = useContext(Context) as {global: any};
  const confirmationCode = props.match.params.confirmationCode;

  async function checkConfirmationCode() {
    const response = await fetch(`${global.apiUrl}/user/confirm_email`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({confirmationCode})
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem("warning", 'confirmed');
    } else if (response.status === 400) {
      localStorage.setItem("warning", 'invalid');
    }
  }

  if (confirmationCode) {
    checkConfirmationCode();
  }

  return (
    <div>test</div>
  );
} 

export default Confirm;
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
  console.log('FIRE Just Once!!!')
}, [])` Add blank array as second argument.

Comment: the call to the api uses the context state for storing the apiUrl as its a global, if i pipe this into the useEffect, the api calls works but again it gets called 3 times, if I hard code the url it calls the api just once, any way around this chicken and egg situation?

Comment: put `apiUrl` in the dependency array of `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

update your `useEffect` hook with following code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (confirmationCode) {
    checkConfirmationCode();
  }
}, [confirmationCode]);
```

Comment: This is the best oop oriented answer, for me

Answer (score -1):

Using this code is one solution.
`useEffect(() => { console.log('FIRE Just Once!!!') }, [])`,

btw if you want to resist multiple function calling,
you can use `debounce` in `lodash` to avoid multiple function call in certain time period.

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
...

const debouncedApiCall = debounce(checkConfirmationCode, 500);
// call `checkConfirmationCode` once in 500ms

...

if (confirmationCode) {
  debouncedApiCall();
}
...
```

REF: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce